# Hide div after click on it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code which works with normal texts and images but I need to hide the `div` after clicking on adsense unite inside it to avoid multiple clicks from the visitors.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#somediv").click(function () {
            $(this).hide()
        });
    });
</script>

<div id="somediv"  onclick="hide()" style="position:absolute";>
    some text  some text  some text  
</div>
```

Comment: Your code works fine (https://jsfiddle.net/a6hbejo2/), do you have an issue with it? Note that you're using an incredibly old version of jQuery which you should update. You should also remove the `onclick` attribute.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan which would run first onclick or the cick event?

Comment: The `onclick` attribute does: https://jsfiddle.net/a6hbejo2/1/, at least for me in Chrome.

Comment: What's the difference between the behavior that you are experiencing and  the expected behavior?

Comment: Why are you having both events? Please don't write onclick() in HTML code.

Comment: thanks very much for your time , yes it works fine with texts and images but need it to work with adsense ad unite .
example : [link](http://selmaneaid.com/test.php)

Comment: Why would you need to hide adsense units? If your users are real people, genuinely following the ads - adsense would not care if they occasionally click the ad twice. If these are bots or you playing some sorts of tricks - you likely in the violation of adsense ToS already.